# Retain value of variable in succeeding function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, global-variables

I have this code, which obtains the class of the clicked hyperlink and toggles the *play* and *pause icons* of a particular div within that hyperlink. I have a problem with the Javascript logic:

```js
var mediaClicked_class = "";
var previousMediaClicked_class = "";
var pauseIconStatus = null;

// Get class of clicked hyperlink
function mediaClick_class(clicked_class) {
  alert(pauseIconStatus + " : Initial pause Icon status");
  mediaClicked_class = clicked_class; // when i click map hyperlink, pass respective class into variable

  preEmptivePlay(mediaClicked_class, pauseIconStatus);
}

function preEmptivePlay(mediaClicked_class, pauseIconStatus) {
  if (pauseIconStatus == null) { //global var. init.
    //toggle class of currently clicked div.icon
    $("div.icon_" + mediaClicked_class).toggleClass("playicon pauseicon");

    var pauseIconAvailability = $("div.icon_" + mediaClicked_class).hasClass("pauseicon");

    if (pauseIconAvailability) { //true - playing
      pauseIconStatus = 1;; //pause icon is active i.e. song is playing
      previousMediaClicked_class = mediaClicked_class; //store current class to be called later
      alert(pauseIconStatus + " : Current icon status");
    } else { //false - not playing
      pauseIconStatus = 0;; //pause icon is inactive i.e. song is not playing
      previousMediaClicked_class = mediaClicked_class;
      alert(pauseIconStatus + " : Current icon status");

    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I click the hyperlink, this function is called, and the fourth line initialises `pauseIconStatus` as `null` everytime, instead of retaining the possible value 0 on subsequent calls.

Where can I declare this variable to initialise as null, then do-away with re-initialisation on subsequent calls?

Comment: Your logic looks fine. It's hard to say what's going wrong without seeing a working example. Are there any errors in the console? Do you see any `alert()`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, the curse of a function with a parameter named after a global strikes again! =) (It took me running it several times for it to finally click that that's what it was)

Comment: @Rob well spotted - I completely missed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're passing in `pauseIconStatus` as a parameter to the function `preEmptivePlay` which means that the changes you make aren't seen outside of that function.

You can see this happen explicitly by adding this line:

```
alert(pauseIconStatus + " : After preEmptivePlay pause Icon status");
```

into `mediaClick_class` immediately after where you call `preEmptivePlay`, you'll see how the value for `pauseIconStatus` is null again because the changes you made inside `preEmptivePlay` never leave the function.

If you change `mediaClick_class` so that it has this instead:

```
pauseIconStatus = preEmptivePlay(mediaClicked_class, pauseIconStatus);
```

And also change `preEmptivePlay` so that the last line (added) is:

```
return pauseIconStatus;
```

You should see that `pauseIconStatus` will stop being `null` for clicks subsequent to the first one.

It may also be that, depending on how `mediaClick_class` is being called, you also need to add `return false;` to the end of the click handler, as otherwise clicking on the hyperlink will result in the page re-loading, e.g. if your page is called default.html and the link looks something like this:

```
<a href="default.html" id="myLink"><div id="icon_thing">Text</div></a>
```

Your wire-up of the `click` event needs to look something like this:

```
$("#myLink").on('click', function ()
{
    mediaClick_class('thing');

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Look at the big brain on Rob! Rob has apparently robbed another man of his brain, cause right now, he has two. Thumbs up!

Comment: @Reeyona, heh, glad I could help =) For what it's worth, consider changing the name of the parameter on `preEmptivePlay` - having a parameter named the same as a global is a really bad idea... as you've seen! =)